# A capacitor as loop filter of a DLL

Tags: oscillator, pll, jitter, phase-noise

I know that if a second order, type two PLL has only a capacitor as its loop filter, it is unstable because its phase margin would be zero. but why is it ok for a DLL to only have a capacitor as its loop filter and it doesn't need the resistor in series with the capacitor to be stable? **(i.e., it doesn't need the zero)** and how does this zero in PLLs improve phase noise near the PLL's bandwidth frequency?

Answer (score 4):

A PLL will measure phase and turn it into a frequency. The VCO in a PLL will perform an integrating action which adds a pole at s=0. This adds 90 degrees phase in the open loop gain. If only a capacitor is used for the loop filter, then this adds another 90 degrees phase and you may get an unstable system. A zero may need to be added to compensate for this.

\$\phi(t)=\phi(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^tf(u)du\Rightarrow\Phi(s)=\frac{F(s)}{s}\$

A DLL does not generate a frequency. There the delay element will generate a delay or phase shift derived from a fixed clock, so there is no integrating action. It just generates a delay/phase shift proportionally. So stability is still possible with only the pole from the loop filter.

Comment: And how does this zero in PLLs improve the phase noise? @Sven B

Comment: The main reason for the zero is to compensate for the pole at s=0. But if you do that, you can increase the open loop gain (because it is more stable) which in turn will reduce noise because the feedback is stronger.